# KendoUI removeRow removes row, but it returns on paging back

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

Right now, I am removing a row just fine on an Ajax call success:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Some/Url',
    success: function () {
        grid.removeRow($(grid.select()));
    }
});
```

`grid` is a kendoGrid object, and the row gets removed just fine.  But if I remove it from page 1 of the grid, navigate to page 2, then back to page 1, it is there again.  Am I doing anything wrong here?  According to the documentation, this should remove it form the grid's dataSource as well, do I need to do anything manually?  Thank you.

Comment: when does your ajax call fires?? I created a fiddle,check out : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sowjanya51/Lmm814v4/)

Comment: Are you sure that you are removing it from the DataSource? I.e. depends on how you define the DataSource that the operation is automatically synchronized sending the remove request to the server and get a response from it and finally get removed or just mark the row as removed but not removing it.

Comment: Andrea, thank you for the example, I will compare.  @OnaBai how is it that I should define my dataSource?  I am deleting via a manual $.ajax call and then removing the row with removeRow.

Comment: If it is a dataSource, why do you need to first remove it from the server (when you call `$.ajax`) and then from the grid (when do `removeRow`)? You should invoke `removeRow` and this should call the `destroy` method in your `DataSource.transport` and here is where you should implement whatever code you need for sending the remove to the server. Doing this, it should correctly remove the row.